# ipad application style/look and feel

Tags: ipad, fonts, uikit, coding-style, look-and-feel

Is there a way to set style or look and feel for ipad application as it works for java applications?

In particular, i want to set my custom Font application-wide, so that all buttons/labels/whatever created would use my Font by default. All that i found so far concerning fonts suggests that every single control i create should be set up individually. Is it so or is there way to set up default Font properties for whole project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually a bad idea from the UI viewpoint, therefore there is no “skinning” support in iOS. (Java has it different, because it wants to support different systems with different UI metaphors.) If you want to use a custom font, you can create custom subclasses of the UI components that will set your font after awaking from NIB or after the instance is created in code.